# Solve involving simple cancellation on both sides fails when there are too many constants

Tags: equation-solving

I've been working with a number of equations of the form `x = A * B * x ^ C` where I need to solve for `x`--basically, equations involving a simple cancellation of powers from both sides.

But it seems that there is some threshold of complexity in `A * B * C` that `Solve[]` cannot handle, even though this part is in some sense computationally irrelevant.

As a general rule, how could I avoid running over such thresholds? Or is there a way to force `Solve[]` to still produce answers?

For example, this works:

```
Solve[
et == et^((gam1 gam2)/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * del0^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * gam2^(1/(2 - gam2)) 
      * kap^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * phit^(1/(2 - gam2)) 
      * (c2^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) K01^(-((2 (1 + del1))/(-2 + gam1))) tet1^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) 
           + c1^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) K02^(-((2 (1 + del1))/(-2 + gam1))) tet2^(gam1/(2 - gam1)))^(1/(2 - gam2))
, et]
```

returning

```
During evaluation of In[128]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

 Out[128]= {{et -> (del0^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2))) gam2^(1/(
 2 - gam2)) kap^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2))) phit^(1/(
 2 - gam2)) (c2^(gam1/(2 - gam1))
     K01^(-(2/(-2 + gam1)) - (2 del1)/(-2 + gam1)) tet1^(gam1/(
    2 - gam1)) + 
   c1^(gam1/(2 - gam1))
     K02^(-(2/(-2 + gam1)) - (2 del1)/(-2 + gam1)) tet2^(gam1/(2 - gam1)))^(1/(2 - gam2)))^(1/(1 - (gam1 gam2)/((2 - gam1) (2 - gam2))))}}
```

But when I multiply just one more term `ct^(1/(-2 + gam2))`on the LHS,

```
Solve[
et == et^((gam1 gam2)/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * del0^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * gam2^(1/(2 - gam2)) 
      * kap^(2/((-2 + gam1) (-2 + gam2)))
      * phit^(1/(2 - gam2)) 
      * (c2^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) K01^(-((2 (1 + del1))/(-2 + gam1))) tet1^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) 
           + c1^(gam1/(2 - gam1)) K02^(-((2 (1 + del1))/(-2 + gam1))) tet2^(gam1/(2 - gam1)))^(1/(2 - gam2))
      * ct^(1/(-2 + gam2))
 , et]
```

it fails:

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>
```

I'm cancelling `et` on both sides to work around this problem, but it seems that this workaround should be unnecessary. Is really multiplying that one more factor on the LHS increasing the complexity above the threshold that `Solve[]` can handle? Any insights / tips about best practices would be much appreciated..

Comment: I don't have an answer to this but rather a general comment about the process under the hood. `Solve` at heart works with polynomials and polynomial systems. It has various tricks to recognize some classes of equation involving symbolic powers of a `Solve` variable. These can show up in different ways and give rise to different types of result, and in some cases a transformation that might improve the chances of recasting the problem can be undone by a later one that seems good but for whatever reason turns out to be bad....

Comment: ...This is particularly an issue when we have possibilities of solutions using reciprocal powers, vs. logarithms, vs `ProductLog`. There might also be cutoff switches, based e.g. on `LeafCount`, that determine what transformations to avoid. Offhand I do not know what goes astray in the nonfunctioning example, but I wanted to give an indication of what are the underlying possibilities.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for your comments. Hard for me to fathom what's going on under the hood...but your indication helped assuage my confusion/curiosity.